# How to turn off the automatic lock?

Tags: 10.04, login, accounts, lock-screen

I want Ubuntu to ask for my password when I log in but not lock me every time I am away for 5 minutes.

How can I disable the automatic lock?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the Gnome desktop, go to *System > Preferences > Screensaver* and turn off the *Lock screen when screensaver is active* checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just another way
 1. Run `gconf-editor` on terminal
 2. Navigate Desktop->Gnome->Lockdown
 3. Click on the checkbox `disable_lock_screen`

See this image:

[image]